# Conditional labels in Mosaic graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating mosaic graphs following this [detailed guide](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2_marimekko_mosaic_chart/). When the value is missing or zero for one category, its label is rendered at the bottom of the graph. If two consecutive categories fall in this condition their labels are rendering over on another:

[image]

I tried adding a condition to the label rendering using `subset`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26869199/2066215):

```
p2 <- p1 + geom_text(data=subset(dfm1, variable > 0), 
                aes(x = xtext, y = ytext,
                label = paste(variable,
                        " - ", value,
                        "", sep = "")), size = 3.5)
```

But this results in an error, with no graph produced:

```
In Ops.factor(variable, 0) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

How can I restrict the labels to values greater than zero?

Comment: you probably want `value > 0`, but its difficult to tell without a reproducible example

Comment: Richard, your suggestion fixed it. Can you please introduce an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variable` is a factor - hence the error. You want to subset by `value > 0`.