# Conditonally add labels to ggplot stacked barplot

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, bar-chart

This is similar to previous questions, but I haven't found a solution that works yet.

I have a stacked barplot in ggplot almost exactly like the one listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869141/conditionally-hiding-data-labels-in-ggplot2-graph?rq=1). Like that user, I only want category labels for those bars with a count > 20. I tried to do the subset solution suggested there as well as an ifelse statement. For the subset solution I get:

```
    Error in n > 20 : comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

My graph:

```
data %>% 
      count(groups, Response) %>%
      mutate(group = factor(groups)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(groups, n, fill=Response)) + 
      geom_col(aes(fill = Response)) +
      geom_text(data=subset(data, n>20), aes(label=n), position=position_stack(0.5), size = 3)
```

I don't know if sharing my data would be useful, but I can do that if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` does not contain `n`, only your piped in anonymous data does, after the `count` function. Here are three solutions:

1.

```
data %>% 
      count(groups, Response) %>%
      mutate(group = factor(groups)) %>% 
      {
        ggplot(., aes(groups, n, fill=Response)) + 
        geom_col(aes(fill = Response)) +
        geom_text(data=filter(., n>20), aes(label=n), position=position_stack(0.5), size = 3)
       }
```

2.

```
counts <- data %>% 
      count(groups, Response) %>%
      mutate(group = factor(groups))

ggplot(counts, aes(groups, n, fill=Response)) + 
      geom_col(aes(fill = Response)) +
      geom_text(data=filter(counts, n>20), aes(label=n), position=position_stack(0.5), size = 3)
```

3.

```
data %>% 
      count(groups, Response) %>%
      mutate(group = factor(groups)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(groups, n, fill=Response)) + 
      geom_col(aes(fill = Response)) +
      geom_text(data=. %>% filter(n>20), aes(label=n), position=position_stack(0.5), size = 3)
```

Comment: That first solution worked great, I really appreciate it. Could you explain what exactly the '.' is doing to help carry 'n' over into geom_text()?

Comment: The `.` is the result of whatever was piped into the `{}`. Your problem is that you are using `data` in `geom_text()`, not the result of the pipe chain. To insert the result of the pipe chain to multiple points of a complex call (such as a bunch of `ggplot` code) you can use the `{}`.